# How to know through APIs who created the file in Shared Drive (Team Drive) in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

All the files in Shared drive (Team Drive) in google drive are accessible by all users who have access to Shared Drive (Team Drive).

When a new file is created in a Shared Drive(Team Drive) by default all the users with access to Shared Drive(Team Drive) will become owners as well.

**Question** : when we list the files using APIs inside a folder in Shared Drive (Team Drive), how to detect who created the file ?

Answer (score 2):

### You can use the [Revisions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)

So, if you list the revisions of a file specifying `revisions/lastModifyingUser, revisions/id` in parameter `fields`, you can retrieve the changes of the file and the corresponding user who modified the file.

Thereby, the first revision (`"id": "1"`) should correspond to the creation / upload of the file and the related `lastModifyingUser` is the creator of the file.

**Additional information:**

- Listing files, will return a files resource with the properties as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) - The resource has properties like "owners" or "lastModifyingUser", but unfortunately not "creator"
- There is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110433610) asking to implement the option to retrieve the user who added a file to a shared drive. - You can "star" it to increase visibility and thus hopefully sooner implementation
- Until then  unfortunately you cannot retrieve the file creator without the workaround with the Revisions API

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will look in to that .

I am making an API call to the list files from a folder, let's say if there are 25 files in that folder to know who created those file, if i use Revision API then i will end up making additional 25 separate calls, is there any way to get the person who created the file 'creator' field when we list the files?

Comment: When you list files, the response will be a `files resource` with the properties as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource). There are properties like "owners" or "lastModifyingUser", but unfortunately not "creator". There is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/110433610) asking to implement the option to retrieve the user who added a file to a shared drive. You can "star" it to increase visibility, but in the meantime unfortunately you cannot retrieve the file creator without the workaround with the Revisions API.