# Is there a way to change the file creator with the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API to make some changes to the files in my shared drives. I see that it's possible to update the created time and the owner, but is there any way to specify a specific creator?

Comment: I cannot understand about "creator" in your question. So can I ask you about the detail of "creator"? For example, where can I see "creator"? Is that different from the owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is not possible to modify neither the file creator, nor the createdTime

- While `createdTime` is a valid property of a [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), you cannot modify this property with a [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) request.

  If you try, you will obtain the error:

  `The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.`
- When it comes to `creator` - this property does not exist and cannot even be read, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666869/how-to-know-through-apis-who-created-the-file-in-shared-drive-team-drive-in-go/62672486#62672486) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/110433610).
- You can retrieve and set an owner, but this is not necessary the same person as the creator.